# Get row index number of first and last rows in a moving window

Tags: r, sliding-window

I have a data frame where:

```
df <- data.frame(position = c(1000,1156,3200,4629,5559,6100,7456,8208,9500,10000),
 col1 = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0))
```

If I wanted to use sliding windows of size 2000, sliding by 1000, (starting from 1000 and ending at 10000) based on the values in `position`, what command can I use to get the row index number of the first and last row of each window? For example, with this data frame, the output would be:

```
|  window   | row_index1 | row_index2 |  
|   1       |     1      |    2       |
|   2       |     3      |    3       |
|   3       |     3      |    4       |
|   4       |     4      |    5       |
|   5       |     5      |    6       |
|   6       |     6      |    7       |
|   7       |     7      |    8       |
|   8       |     8      |    10      |
```

The output doesn't have to be in table format, I'm just looking for a command to get the index number of the first and last row in each window.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why is 1000 included in window 1, but 10 000 included in window 8 (and not 9)?

Comment: @DonaldSeinen i wanted the sliding windows to end at 10 000, because that is the max value in the `position` column. like the first sliding window would be 1000 to 3000, and then the last one would be 8000 to 10 000, so 8 windows total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a base R approach with findInterval (given that df$position seems sorted). This results in a matrix, but you can easily convert into other data structures.

```r
df <- data.frame(position = c(1000,1156,3200,4629,5559,6100,7456,8208,9500,10000),
                 col1 = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0))

lims <- 1000*cbind(1:8, 1:8+2)

apply(lims, 1, function(x){
ind <- findInterval(x, df$position)
## you will need to add 1 to the first index given, because findInterval tells 
## you the index of the last value below your limit
c(ind[1]+1, ind[length(ind)])
}
)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#> [1,]    2    3    3    4    5    6    7    8
#> [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8   10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>